# How can I prevent re render of react functional components if no props changed

Tags: reactjs, rerender, react-usememo, react-usecallback

Description:
I have a component imported in a loop in the Main component and whenever I update the state, the looped components are also re-rendered. So, how can I prevent them to render if no change is applied to the props of the component?

Eg:

```
const child1 = ({val}) => {
    console.log("CHILD1 RENDERED")
    return (
        <>
            {val}
        </>
    )
}


const main = () => {
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
    const loopArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];


    return (
        <>
            {
                loopArr.map((item) => <child1 val={item}/>)
            }

            {number}

            <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 1)}>Increment</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: You can use React.memo, check the docs

Comment: Show some code plz... Or a MRE --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Wrap `child1` and `child2` with `React.memo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `React.memo` like so:

```
import { memo } from "react";

const Child2 = () => {
  console.log("CHILD2 RENDERED");

  return <div>Child2</div>;
};

export const MemoizedChild = memo(Child2);
```

Here is an example: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/white-snow-8peizi?file=/src/Child2.js:0-164).